# How to store dozen of 2D static arrays inside dynamic structure in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I have ROI placed in image captured from a camera. I am reading HSV values of area inside that ROI, but I don't know how can I store 3 element arrays into some dynamic structure. I tried using `C++ vector` container, but it seems that OpenCV doesn't support it (i have some exception errors).

**Errors:**

[image]

```
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: int const & __thiscall std::_Vector_const_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<int> > >::operator*(void)const " (??D?$_Vector_const_iterator@V?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@H@std@@@std@@@std@@QBEABHXZ)  D:\Moje Dokumenty\--STUDIA\MATERIAŁY, SKRYPTY\--Magisterka\Projekt Zespołowy\testowe\22-marca\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   ConsoleApplication1
Error   14  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\Moje Dokumenty\--STUDIA\MATERIAŁY, SKRYPTY\--Magisterka\Projekt Zespołowy\testowe\22-marca\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1   1   ConsoleApplication1
```

**My code is:**

```
vector<int> detectColor( int x, int y, int outerA, int outerZ, int innerA, int innerZ)
{

        vector<int> vectorContainer,
        vectorMinimum,
        vectorMaximum;

        Mat image=imgOriginal.clone();
        Vec3b rgb=image.at<Vec3b>(y,x);
        int B=rgb.val[0];
        int G=rgb.val[1];
        int R=rgb.val[2];

        Mat HSV;
        Mat RGB=image(Rect(x,y,1,1));
        cvtColor(RGB, HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);

        Vec3b hsv=HSV.at<Vec3b>(0,0);
        int H=hsv.val[0];
        int S=hsv.val[1];
        int V=hsv.val[2];

        Mat rectRGB,
            rectHSV;

        Vec3b rectHSVSingle;

        int minH = 179,
            minS = 255,
            minV = 255,

            maxH = 0,
            maxS = 0,
            maxV = 0;


        for (int i = outerA; i <= outerZ; i++)
        {

            for (int j = innerA; j <= innerZ; j++)
            {

                rectRGB = image(Rect(i, j, 1, 1));
                cvtColor(rectRGB , rectHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
                rectHSVSingle = rectHSV.at<Vec3b>(0,0);

                int singleH = rectHSVSingle.val[0];
                int singleS = rectHSVSingle.val[1];
                int singleV = rectHSVSingle.val[2];


                // Find minimum HSV values
                if (minH > singleH)
                    minH = singleH;

                if (minS > singleS)
                    minS = singleS;

                if (minV > singleV)
                    minV = singleV;

                // Find maximum HSV values
                if (maxH < singleH)
                    maxH = singleH;

                if (maxS < singleS)
                    maxS = singleS;

                if (maxV < singleV)
                    maxV = singleV;

            }
        }   

        cout << "H: " << H << " S: " << S << " V: " << V << endl;
        cout << "minH: " << minH << " minS: " << minS << " minV: " << minV << endl;
        cout << "maxH: " << maxH << " maxS: " << maxS << " maxV: " << maxV << endl;

vectorMinimum.push_back(minH);
vectorMinimum.push_back(minS);
vectorMinimum.push_back(minV);

vectorMaximum.push_back(maxH);
vectorMaximum.push_back(maxS);
vectorMaximum.push_back(maxV);      

vectorContainer.insert(end(vectorContainer), begin(vectorMinimum), end(vectorMinimum));
    vectorContainer.insert(end(vectorContainer), begin(vectorMaximum), end(vectorMaximum));   

return vectorContainer; 
}
```

It works (**wthout vectors** - when function is declarated as void), when I launch `detectColor()` function once. But I want to store `minH`, `minS` and `minV` as well as `maxH`, `maxS`, `maxV` in two, separate arrays (or maybe 2D array), which then I want to return (from `detectColor()` function) and **push it into dynamic structure** as dynamic array (or vector).

**The problem is**, that the size of that dynamic structure is unknown at the beginning - as I want to use `detectColor()` function as something like a object scanner (I mean object, that I detect in front of camera).

There are 4 ROIs on below image, but in fact I want to have one, small, ROI. Then I'll be moving object inside it's area to scan it (measure it's minimum and maximum HSV values). That's why I need to gather min/max values in some storage and after that, calculate min/max average values. That function will finish when `spacebar` button pressed - it will run by flexible amount of time, so i need dynamic array of min/max values.

[image]

**Structure of that dynamic collection should look like that** (pseudo code):

```
dynamicStructure = {
    [ // first array
      [minH, minS, minV], // 1st sub-array
      [maxH, maxS, maxV]  // 2nd sub-array
    ],
    [ // second array
      [minH, minS, minV], // 1st sub-array
      [maxH, maxS, maxV]  // 2nd sub-array
    ],
    [ // third array
      [minH, minS, minV], // 1st sub-array
      [maxH, maxS, maxV]  // 2nd sub-array
    ],
    [ // fourth array
      [minH, minS, minV], // 1st sub-array
      [maxH, maxS, maxV]  // 2nd sub-array
    ],
      // n-th array
   /.../, // unknown amount of arrays inside `dynamicStructure`
}
```

Comment: I edited my post (added code with errors). However if that vectors cannot be used with OpenCV, how then do it in another way (using OpenCV `Mat` maybe or other kind of dynamic structure)?

Comment: Any ideas about errors or my question?